# When I try to install PySide, I get an error

Tags: python

I typed in the console `pip install PySide` and then I have an error:

ERROR: Complete output from command 'C:\Python34\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='"'"'C:\Users\formin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-geki9hcv\PySide\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\formin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-vnum7mxf\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
ERROR: Removing C:\Users\formin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-geki9hcv\PySide\pyside_package
running install
running build
Python architecture is 64bit
nmake was found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\nmake.exe
Inserting path "C:\Users\formin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-geki9hcv\PySide\pyside_install\py3.4-qt4.8.6-64bit-release\bin" to environment
==============================
Package version: 1.2.4
Build type: Release
Build tests: False
---
Make path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\nmake.exe
Make generator: NMake Makefiles
Make jobs:
---
Script directory: C:\Users\formin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-geki9hcv\PySide
Sources directory: C:\Users\formin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-geki9hcv\PySide\sources
Build directory: C:\Users\formin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-geki9hcv\PySide\pyside_build\py3.4-qt4.8.6-64bit-release
Install directory: C:\Users\formin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-geki9hcv\PySide\pyside_install\py3.4-qt4.8.6-64bit-release
Python site-packages install directory: C:\Users\formin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-geki9hcv\PySide\pyside_install\py3.4-qt4.8.6-64bit-release\Lib\site-packages
---
Python executable: C:\Python34\python.exe
Python includes: C:\Python34\include
Python library: C:\Python34\libs\python34.lib
Python prefix: C:\Python34
Python scripts: C:\Python34\Scripts
---
Qt qmake: C:\Qt\4.8.6\bin\qmake.exe
Qt version: 4.8.6
Qt bins: C:\Qt\4.8.6\bin
Qt plugins: C:\Qt\4.8.6\plugins
---
OpenSSL libs: None
==============================
Creating build folder C:\Users\formin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-geki9hcv\PySide\pyside_build\py3.4-qt4.8.6-64bit-release...
Creating install folder C:\Users\formin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-geki9hcv\PySide\pyside_install\py3.4-qt4.8.6-64bit-release...
Building module shiboken...
Creating module build folder C:\Users\formin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-geki9hcv\PySide\pyside_build\py3.4-qt4.8.6-64bit-release\shiboken...
Configuring module shiboken (C:\Users\formin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-geki9hcv\PySide\sources\shiboken)...
Running process: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -G "NMake Makefiles" -DQT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE=C:\Qt\4.8.6\bin\qmake.exe -DBUILD_TESTS=False -DDISABLE_DOCSTRINGS=True -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\Users\formin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-geki9hcv\PySide\pyside_install\py3.4-qt4.8.6-64bit-release C:\Users\formin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-geki9hcv\PySide\sources\shiboken -DPYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=C:\Python34\python.exe -DPYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR=C:\Python34\include -DPYTHON3_LIBRARY=C:\Python34\libs\python34.lib -DCMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX=_d -DCMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH=yes -DUSE_PYTHON3=ON
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 16.0.40219.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 16.0.40219.1
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/bin/amd64/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/bin/amd64/cl.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:60 (message):
The C compiler

```
    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/bin/amd64/cl.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: C:/Users/formin/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-geki9hcv/PySide/pyside_build/py3.4-qt4.8.6-64bit-release/shiboken/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):nmake /nologo cmTC_aa0f5\fast &&   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\nmake.exe" -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_aa0f5.dir\build.make /nologo -L                  CMakeFiles\cmTC_aa0f5.dir\build

    Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_aa0f5.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
            C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1.0\VC\bin\amd64\cl.exe @C:\Users\formin\AppData\Local\Temp\nmC3A3.tmp
    testCCompiler.c
    Linking C executable cmTC_aa0f5.exe
            "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_aa0f5.dir --rc=C:\PROGRA~1\MIA713~1\Windows\v7.1\Bin\RC.Exe --mt=C:\PROGRA~1\MIA713~1\Windows\v7.1\Bin\mt.exe --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1.0\VC\bin\amd64\link.exe /nologo @CMakeFiles\cmTC_aa0f5.dir\objects1.rsp @C:\Users\formin\AppData\Local\Temp\nmC3E3.tmp
    LINK Pass 1: command "C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1.0\VC\bin\amd64\link.exe /nologo @CMakeFiles\cmTC_aa0f5.dir\objects1.rsp /out:cmTC_aa0f5.exe /implib:cmTC_aa0f5.lib /pdb:C:\Users\formin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-geki9hcv\PySide\pyside_build\py3.4-qt4.8.6-64bit-release\shiboken\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_aa0f5.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:CMakeFiles\cmTC_aa0f5.dir/intermediate.manifest CMakeFiles\cmTC_aa0f5.dir/manifest.res" failed (exit code 1104) with the following output:
    LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"' : return code '0xffffffff'
    Stop.
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
    Stop.





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/formin/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-geki9hcv/PySide/pyside_build/py3.4-qt4.8.6-64bit-release/shiboken/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/formin/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-geki9hcv/PySide/pyside_build/py3.4-qt4.8.6-64bit-release/shiboken/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
error: Error configuring shiboken
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command "'C:\Python34\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='"'"'C:\Users\formin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-geki9hcv\PySide\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\formin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-vnum7mxf\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\formin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-geki9hcv\PySide\

Is there a way to install Qt for Python (PySide2) using pip which is suitable to my PC and doesn't make any errors in the console.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to create a comment. I think your question fits better to StackOverflow, since you do not ask for a recommendation (for example "which library can I use to do x?").

Comment: Upvote.  People do ask questions like this on S.O, but really it belongs on https://superuser.com/